# SharePoint list Form footer formatting - Multiple text lines

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, list-form

Does anybody knows how can I add two lines in a footer in SharePoint form?

I found tutorials teaching how to add two links to the footer, but I need to be able to place two notices, one under the other.

[image: Example]

I need to add a line with this text "⚠️ Anexe apenas o formulário do fornecedor", below the other text line, this is my actual JSON:

```
{
    "debugMode": false,
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "width": "100%",
        "text-align": "left",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-top-width": "1px"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "width": "100%",
                "padding-top": "10px",
                "height": "24px"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "txtContent": " ⚠️ Caso trate-se de cadastro de pessoa física (CPF) não é necessário a verificação dos dados, prossiga via MDG.",
                    "attributes": {
                        "target": "_blank",
                        "class": "ms-fontColor-black ms-borderColor-themePrimary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-m ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary–hover ms-bgColor-themeLight–hover"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want this as a hyperlink or just simple text?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this below `"⚠️ Caso trate-se de cadastro...` ?

Remember to adjust the height to accommodate the second line.

```
...
           {
                "elmType": "a",
                "txtContent": "⚠️ Anexe apenas o formulário do fornecedor",
                "attributes": {
                    "target": "_blank",
                    "class": "ms-fontColor-black ms-borderColor-themePrimary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-m ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary–hover ms-bgColor-themeLight–hover"
                }
...
```

Try this and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It worked! Thank you, you helped me a lot 

Comment: @ygbarelli Im glad it worked! Please mark it as the answer so that others may find it easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to add the plain text, you should not use `a` element type.

Instead, try using this JSON for footer layout:

```
{
    "debugMode": false,
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "width": "100%",
        "text-align": "left",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-top-width": "1px"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "width": "100%",
                "padding-top": "10px"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-black ms-borderColor-themePrimary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-m ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary–hover ms-bgColor-themeLight–hover"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": " ⚠️ Caso trate-se de cadastro de pessoa física (CPF) não é necessário a verificação dos dados, prossiga via MDG."
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": " ⚠️ Anexe apenas o formulário do fornecedor"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]